# MSBuild windows 2012 Visual Studio 2015 cannot find AxImp.exe

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to set up Jenkins in a Windows Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2015 and I cannot build my application using MSBuild, I get some Windows SDK issue.

> (ResolveComReferences target) ->
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2015,5):
>   error MSB3091: Task failed because "AxImp.exe" was not found, or the
>   correct Microsoft Windows SDK is not installed. The task is looking
>   for "AxImp.exe" in the "bin" subdirectory beneath the location
>   specified in the InstallationFolder value of the registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86. You may be able to solve
>   the problem by doing one of the following:  1) Install the Microsoft
>   Windows SDK.  2) Install Visual Studio 2010.  3) Manually set the
>   above registry key to the correct location.  4) Pass the correct
>   location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the task.

I've tried the following:

- Create the Registry key pointing to the SDK installed. No sucess.
- Uninstall all C++ Compilers, download Windows 7 SDK iso and install, as explained [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1de7c9b4-1feb-4c98-b426-f7f02cbafa99/windows-sdk-71-on-windows-10?forum=windowssdk). No success.
- Modify Visual Studio 2015 installation adding and removing components, marking explicitly SDKs to be installed. No success.

When building from Visual Studio it builds fine.

I really don't know what's happening here and why I cannot get it working, seems a bug to me regarding Windows or Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: In case you are running R2, did you install the [Update 2919355](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355) as explained under [Visual Studio 2015 System Requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx)?

Comment: Yes I did, but I did not have any success.

Comment: What project you build? Try to install Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8 (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-sdk)

Comment: It's an MVC 5 project the one which is not building... I don't know why is it depending on the Windows SDK at all, probably some MSBuild common targets are referencing to it, because the .csproj doesn't mention any SDK explicitly.

Comment: The windows 8 SDK thing didn't solve the issue, either.

Comment: Can you check if "axlmp.exe" exist in the installation folder? You can get the installation folder from "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86".

Comment: That key did not exist, so I created one and added an InstallationFolder key pointing to the 7.1 SDK, but MSBuild seems not to find it or something because I get the same message. I've searched how to change the SDK to use, but it seems it's not possible, or I don't know how to do it. Another approach is changing the "ToolPath" parameter of the task, but I don't know which tasks it refers to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was much easier than it seemed to be, just changing the ToolsVersion of the Project node from 4.0 to 14.0 made the trick:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had a really similar issue, using Jenkins and Msbuild to build projects, and getting this same error.

My solution steps:

1. first find out IF Aximp.exe exist on the Jenkins machine.  I don't have access to the machine, so I included a stage in my jenkinsfile to run this command:

   ```
   //temp, try and get location of aximp.exe on build machine

   bat 'dir "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows" /b /s aximp.exe'
   ```

   I then reviewed the output to see where it lives.
2. then, I added a parameter to my msbuild command in my jenkinsfile like this:

   ```
   bat 'msbuild mysolution.sln  /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 "/p:TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v10.0A\\bin\\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools" '   //your folder where aximp.exe lives
   ```

And the build now runs!